# The relationship between auto and decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, type-inference, decltype

Is

```
auto x = initializer;
```

equivalent to

```
decltype(initializer) x = initializer;
```

or

```
decltype((initializer)) x = initializer;
```

or neither?

Comment: This Q&A has some good answers, but it should be closed as a dupe of other canonicals because it lacks focus. It is asking (1) what the relationship between `auto` and `decltype` is, and (2) what the difference between `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` is, due to how it's phrased. The answers are overly verbose and reflect this lack of focus.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`decltype` also considers whether the expression is `rvalue` or `lvalue` .

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Type_inference),

> **The type denoted by decltype can be different from the type deduced by auto.**

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v(1);
    auto a = v[0];        // a has type int
    decltype(v[0]) b = 1; // b has type const int&, the return type of
                        // std::vector<int>::operator[](size_type) const
    auto c = 0;           // c has type int
    auto d = c;           // d has type int
    decltype(c) e;        // e has type int, the type of the entity named by c
    decltype((c)) f = c;  // f has type int&, because (c) is an lvalue
    decltype(0) g;        // g has type int, because 0 is an rvalue
}
```

That pretty much explains the imporant  difference. Notice `decltype(c)` and `decltype((c))` are not same!

And sometime `auto` and `decltype` works *together* in a cooperative way, such as in the following example (taken from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype), and modified a bit):

```
int& foo(int& i);
float foo(float& f);

template <class T>
auto f(T& t) −> decltype(foo(t)) 
{
  return foo(t);
}
```

Wikipedia further [explains the semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype#Semantics) of `decltype` as follows:

> Similarly to the sizeof operator, the operand of decltype is unevaluated. Informally, the type returned by decltype(e) is deduced as follows:
>
> - If the expression e refers to a variable in local or namespace scope, a static member variable or a function parameter, then the result is that variable's or parameter's declared type
> - If e is a function call or an overloaded operator invocation, decltype(e) denotes the declared return type of that function
> - Otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e; if e is an rvalue, the result is T
>
> These semantics were designed to fulfill the needs of generic library writers, while at the same time being intuitive for novice programmers, because the return type of decltype always matches the type of the object or function exactly as declared in the source code. More formally, Rule 1 applies to unparenthesized id-expressions and class member access expressions. For function calls, the deduced type is the return type of the statically chosen function, as determined by the rules for overload resolution. Example:

```
const int&& foo();
int i;
struct A { double x; };
const A* a = new A();
decltype(foo()) x1; // type is const int&&
decltype(i) x2; // type is int
decltype(a->x) x3; // type is double
decltype((a->x)) x4; // type is const double&
```

> **The reason for the difference between the latter two invocations of decltype is that the parenthesized expression (a->x) is neither an id-expression nor a member access expression, and therefore does not denote a named object.Because the expression is an lvalue, its deduced type is "reference to the type of the expression", or const double&.**

Comment: The wikipedia text isn't correct anymore: `decltype(operator-expression)` doesn't look at the statically declared return type anymore in the FDIS.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Can you show a case where is makes a difference?

Comment: @curiousguy in `const int operator+(A, B)` and in `void(&&operator+(A, B))();`. First would yield `const int` and `void(&&)()` when using the statically declared return type, and with inspecting the expression type and value category yields `int` and `void(&)()`

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb OK, this `void(&&)()` thing is... subtle. Never thought of it.

Comment: @Nawaz In your code snippet `auto f(T& t) −> decltype(foo(t)){} `, is it equivalent to `decltype(auto) f(T& t) {}` ??

Comment: @blueskin: Yes. But that is available since C++14.

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks, I just wanted to make sure am understanding it correctly.

Comment: This is a high-quality answer and it would be worth splitting it up, and adding it to the duplication targets.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What are `void(&&operator+(A, B))();` and `void(&)()`? I couldn't decipher them.

Comment: @palapapa the first is a function that returns an rvalue reference to another function. If written as `using R = void(); R &&operator+(A,A)` it is more readable. The second is an lvalue reference to function type.

Answer (score 9):

This won't work (and is ugly):

```
decltype([]() { foo(); }) f = []() { foo(); };
```

whereas

```
auto f = []() { foo(); };
```

will.

Answer (score 8):

It depends. `auto` and `decltype` serve different purposes so they don't map one-to-one.

The rules for `auto` are the easiest to explain because they are the same as for template parameter deduction. I won't expand on them here, but note that `auto&` and `auto&&` are also some possible uses!

`decltype` however has several cases, some of which you have illustrated above (information and quotes taken from n3290, 7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]) that I separate into two categories:

- when using what the Standard calls "an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access"
- the rest!

Informally, I'd say that `decltype` can operate on either *names* (for the first case) or *expressions*. (Formally and according to the grammar `decltype` operates on expressions, so think of the first case as a refinement and the second case as a catch-all.)

When using a name with decltype, you get the *declared* type of that entity. So for instance `decltype(an_object.a_member)` is the type of the member as it appears in the class definition. On the other hand, if we use `decltype( (an_object.a_member) )` we find ourselves in the catch-all case and we're inspecting the type of the expression *as it would appear in code*.

Accordingly, how to cover all the cases of your questions:

```
int initializer;
auto x = initializer; // type int
// equivalent since initializer was declared as int
decltype(initializer) y = initializer;
```

```
enum E { initializer };
auto x = initializer; // type E
// equivalent because the expression is a prvalue of type E
decltype( (initializer) ) y = initializer;
```

```
struct {
    int const& ializer;
} init { 0 };
auto x = init.ializer; // type int
// not equivalent because declared type is int const&
// decltype(init.ializer) y = init.ializer;
// not equivalent because the expression is an lvalue of type int const&
// decltype( (init.ializer) ) y = init.ializer;
```

Answer (score 3):

## `auto`

`auto` is simple: it will give the same type as by-value template parameter deduction. `auto` works uniformly on expressions.

```
template <class T>
void deduce(T x);

int &refint();
std::string str();
std::string const conststr();

auto i1 = 1; // deduce(1) gives T=int so int i1
auto i2 = i1; // deduce(i1) gives T=int so int i2
auto i3 = refint(); // deduce(refint()) gives T=int so int i3
const auto ci1 = i1; // deduce(i1) gives T=int so const int ci1
auto i4 = ci1; // deduce(ci1) gives T=int so int i4

auto s1 = std::string(); // std::string s1
auto s2 = str(); // std::string s2
auto s3 = conststr(); // std::string s3
```

In C++ expressions cannot have reference type (`refint()` has type `int` not `int&`).

Note that the lvalueness of the expression is not an issue on an expression on the right (on the right of equal sign, or something which is being copied in general). The rvalue `1` is treated like the lvalues `i1` and `refint()`.

For by value parameters (that is, non reference parameters), not only lvalue to rvalue conversion is applied, but also array to pointer conversions. const is ignored.

## `decltype`

`decltype` is a very useful feature with an horrible interface:

`decltype` acts differently on some expressions defined in term of name lookup and other expressions! This is the type of features that make people hate C++.

### `decltype` of something named

`decltype(entity)` will do name lookup and give the declared type of the entity. (`entity` can be an unqualified or qualified identifier, or a member access such as `expr.identifier`.)

`decltype(f(args))` will do name lookup and overload resolution and give the declared return type of the function, not the type the expression:

```
extern decltype(refint()) ri1; // int &ri1
```

So now I can check my understanding of the language with `decltype`:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct sametype {};

template <class T>
struct sametype<T,T> {typedef int same;};
```

`sametype<T,U>::same` exists *iff* `T` and `U` are exactly the same type.

```
sametype<decltype (i1), int>::same check_i1;
sametype<decltype (i2), int>::same check_i2;
sametype<decltype (i3), int>::same check_i3;
sametype<decltype (i4), int>::same check_i4;

sametype<decltype (ci1), const int>::same check_ci1;
sametype<decltype (ir1), int&>::same check_ir1;

sametype<decltype (s1), std::string>::same check_s1;
sametype<decltype (s2), std::string>::same check_s2;
sametype<decltype (s3), std::string>::same check_s3;
```

[compiles fine](http://ideone.com/gRZnbN), so I was not wrong!

### `decltype` of other expressions

Otherwise, where `expr` *is not defined in term of name lookup* (not one of the above cases), such as the expression `(expr)`, `decltype` implements a distinct feature (but the C++ designers would not spent another keywords on it.)

`decltype(expr)` will give the type of the expression decorated with its lxrvalueness (lvalue/xvalue/prvalue-ness):

- prvalue (pure rvalue) of type `T` gives `T`
- xvalue of type `T` gives `T&&`
- lvalue of type `T` gives `T&`

This is the reciprocal of function call rule: if `f` is a function with return type

- `T&`, the expression `f()` is an lvalue
- `T&&`, the expression `f()` is an xvalue
- naked type (pure object type, non reference) `T`, the expression `f()` is a prvalue

and also for casts: for naked type (pure object type, non reference) `T`

- `(T&)expr` is a lvalue
- `(T&&)expr` is an xvalue
- `(T)expr` is a prvalue

Reference-ness is the encoding of lxrvalueness into types. `decltype` does this encoding to save and transfer the lxrvalueness of things.

This is useful when you want to alias an expression: the lxrvalueness of an expression `expr` that is a function call (either normal `f(args)` or with operator syntax like `a @ b`) is the same as the lxrvalueness of `alias()` declared as `decltype(expr) alias();`

This can be used for pure forwarding in generic code:

```
// decorated type of an expression
#define EXPR_DEC_TYPE(expr) decltype((expr))

int i;
int &ri = i;
int fi();
int &fri();

EXPR_DEC_TYPE(i) alias_i = i; // int &
EXPR_DEC_TYPE(ri) alias_ri = ri; // int &

EXPR_DEC_TYPE(fi()) alias_fi(); // int alias_fi()
EXPR_DEC_TYPE(fri()) alias_fri(); // int &alias_fri()
```

Note that `EXPR_DEC_TYPE(foo())` equals `declexpr(foo())` by design (in most cases), but the computations are different:

- `declexpr(foo(args))` does name lookup for `foo`, does overload
  resolution, finds the declaration, returns the exact return type
  declared, end of story
- `EXPR_DEC_TYPE(foo(args))` finds the type of the declaration then
  computes

  - the type `T` of the expression which is the return type naked (without
    reference)
  - the lxrvalueness *LXR* of the expression according to the referenceness 
    of the declared return type: lvalue for reference, xvalue of r-reference...

  then it decorates the type `T` with *LXR* to obtain the `decT` type:

  - `decT` is `T` if *LXR* = prvalue
  - `decT` is `T&&` if *LXR* = xvalue
  - `decT` is `T&` if *LXR* = lvalue

  `EXPR_DEC_TYPE` returns `decT` which is the same as the declared return type.

Comment: This is a high-quality answer and it would be worth splitting it up, and adding it to the duplication targets.

Answer (score 0):

1. If `initializer` is an array then `decltype(x)` or `decltype((x))`
   don't work simply on it. However `auto` will be deduced to a
   pointer.
2. If `initializer` is a function then applying `decltype(fp)` will
   deduce to the function type however, `auto` will deduce to its
   return type.

So in general `auto` cannot be considered as a replacement of any `decltype()` version you asked.

Comment: @downvoter please care to explain. Have I state anything wrong ?

Comment: I did not downvote, but in your second point, you mention that type of `var` in `auto var = f` (where `f` is `int f()`) is `int`. However, since you didn't call the function, the actual type of `var` is `int (*)()`. And `decltype(f())` will indeed resolve to `int`. See it [here](http://ideone.com/zSVsy).

Comment: @Vitus, I have mentioned `decltype(f)` and not `decltype(f())`; and I had checked it before posting it. See demo: http://www.ideone.com/fIh13; still this downvote is not justified; it's sad. :(

Comment: Yes, but you cannot compare `auto a = f();` (where you **call** the function) and `decltype(f) a;` (where you **do not**). That was point of my first comment.

Comment: you are saying that `auto x = printf` would be `int`. But that's not the case at all. What @Vitus said. Not sure what that ideone code is meant to demonstrate.