# equivalence between decltype and auto

Tags: c++, type-inference, auto, decltype

Since auto and decltype are both used to infer the types. I thought
they would be same.

However, the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6869888/811335) question suggests otherwise.

Still I think they cannot be entirely different.
I can think of a simple example where the type of `i` will be same in both the following cases.

```
auto i = 10; and decltype(10) i = 10;
```

So what are the possible situations where auto and decltype would behave equivalently.

Comment: You're repeating the 10 in the second definition. Isn't this enough difference ? It is for me. `auto` is *way* more useful in everyday's life than `decltype`, which is mainly used as a metaprogramming tool.

Comment: For now, I am only concerned about the inferred type.

Comment: They are not entirely different. What about the other answer do you now like?

Answer (score 7):

`auto` behaves *exactly* the same as template argument deduction, meaning if you don't specify a reference to it, you don't get one. `decltype` is just the type of an expression and as such takes references into account:

```
#include <type_traits>

int& get_i(){ static int i = 5; return i; }

int main(){
  auto i1 = get_i(); // copy
  decltype(get_i()) i2 = get_i(); // reference
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i1), int>::value, "wut");
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i2), int&>::value, "huh");
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/c2PM9)

Comment: auto can be used in conjunction with decltype too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537655.aspx

Comment: @0A0D: That's just the late-specified return type.

Comment: More specifically, `decltype` converts the value category of its expression into a reference qualification:  an lvalue is qualified as an lvalue reference and an xvalue is qualified as an rvalue reference.  The type of `get_i()` is not "`int&`," it is "an lvalue of type `int`.  An expression never has reference type.

Comment: @James: Indeed, thought I'd keep it simple, though.