# What is the difference between decltype and auto as a placeholder type for variables?

Tags: c++, type-inference, auto, decltype

As I understand it, both `decltype` and `auto` will attempt to figure out what the type of something is.

If we define:

```
int foo () {
    return 34;
}
```

Then both declarations are legal:

```
auto x = foo();
cout << x << endl;

decltype(foo()) y = 13;
decltype(auto)  y = 13; // alternatively, since C++14
cout << y << endl;
```

Could you please tell me what the main difference between `decltype` and `auto` is?

Comment: @JesseGood Before asking the question, I read that thread and am looking for a cleaner explanation

Comment: Similar questions:
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459928/equivalence-between-decltype-and-auto
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869888/the-relationship-between-auto-and-decltype

Comment: @JamesLeonard: Okay, well I don't know a better explanation [than the one by Scott Meyers](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/04/appearing-and-disappearing-consts-in-c/).

Comment: Clearly explained by Scott Meyers in youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU&t=1468s

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`decltype` gives the *declared* type of the expression that is passed to it. `auto` does the  same thing as template type deduction. So, for example, if you have a function that returns a reference, `auto` will still be a value (you need `auto&` to get a reference), but `decltype` will be exactly the type of the return value.

```
#include <iostream>
int global{};

int& foo()
{
   return global;
}
 
int main()
{
    decltype(foo()) a = foo(); //a is an `int&`
 // decltype(auto)  a = foo();   alternatively, since C++14

    auto b = foo(); //b is an `int`
    b = 2;
    
    std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n'; //prints "a: 0"
    std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n'; //prints "b: 2"
    std::cout << "---\n";

    decltype(foo()) c = foo(); //c is an `int&`
 // decltype(auto)  c = foo();   alternatively, since C++14
    c = 10;
    
    std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n'; //prints "a: 10"
    std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n'; //prints "b: 2"
    std::cout << "c: " << c << '\n'; //prints "c: 10"
 }
```

Also see David Rodríguez's answer about the places in which only one of `auto` or `decltype` are possible.

Answer (score 52):

**This is a C++11 answer to a C++11 question**

`auto` (in the context where it infers a type) is limited to defining the type of a variable for which there is an initializer. `decltype` is a broader construct that, at the cost of extra information, will infer the type of an expression.

In the cases where `auto` can be used, it is more concise than `decltype`, as you don't need to provide the expression from which the type will be inferred.

```
auto x = foo();                           // more concise than `decltype(foo()) x`
std::vector<decltype(foo())> v{ foo() };  // cannot use `auto`
```

The keyword `auto` is also used in a completely unrelated context, when using trailing return types for functions:

```
auto foo() -> int;
```

There `auto` is only a leader so that the compiler knows that this is a declaration with a trailing return type. While the example above can be trivially converted to old style, in generic programming it is useful:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto sum( T t, U u ) -> decltype(t+u)
```

Note that in this case, `auto` cannot be used to define the return type.

Comment: I compiled this code without decltype and it worked fine. gave correct type.

Comment: @ŽarkoTomičić: Yes, this is a somewhat outdated answer to an old question.  The answer is correct in C++11, but C++14 introduced *return type deduction* and now you can use `auto f() { return <something>; }` with the compiler deducing the type of the function from the body

Answer (score 3):

That's my thinking about the auto and decltype:

The most obvious difference in pratice between the two is:

- In type deduction for expr, `decltype` deduce the correct type( except the lvalue expr -> lvalue ref) and `auto` default to value.

We need to learn the **"data stream"** model before understanding the difference.

In our codes, the function calling can be resolved as a data stream model(something like the concept of functional program), so the function which is been called is the **data receiver**, and the caller is the **data provider**. It is obviously that the data type must be decided by the **data receiver**, or the data cannot be organized in order in the data stream.

Look this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo(T t){
    // do something.
}
```

the T will be deduced to a value type, regardless of whether you pass.
If you want the ref type, you should use `auto&` or `auto&&`, that's what I am saying, the data type is decided by the data receiver.

Let's return to the `auto`:

`auto` is used to do a type deduction for rvalue expr, giving the **data receiver** a correct interface to receive the data.

```cpp
auto a = some expr; // a is data receiver, and the expr is the provider.
```

So why dose `auto` ignore the ref modifier?
because it should be decided by the receiver.

#### Why we need decltype?

The answer is : `auto` cannot to be used as a true type deduction, it will not give you the correct type of a expr. It just give the data receiver a correct type to receive the data.

So, we need decltype to get the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you need a type for a variable you are going to initialize, use ***auto***. ***decltype*** is better used when you need the type for something that is not a variable, like a return type.

Comment: Good point on the initialization section

Answer (score 0):

modify @Mankarse's example code,I think a better one blew:

```
#include <iostream>
int global = 0;
int& foo()
{
   return global;
}

int main()
{
    decltype(foo()) a = foo(); //a is an `int&`
    auto b = foo(); //b is an `int`
    b = 2;

    std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n'; //prints "a: 0"
    std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n'; //prints "b: 2"
    std::cout << "global: " << global << '\n'; //prints "global: 0"

    std::cout << "---\n";

    //a is an `int&`
    a = 10;

    std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n'; //prints "a: 10"
    std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n'; //prints "b: 2"
    std::cout << "global: " << global << '\n'; //prints "global: 10"

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I consider auto to be a purely simplifying feature whereas the primary purpose of decltype is
> to enable sophisticated metaprogramming in foundation libraries. They are however very closely
> related when looked at from a language-technical point of use.

From [HOPL20](https://www.stroustrup.com/hopl20main-p5-p-bfc9cd4--final.pdf) 4.2.1, Bjarne Stroustrup.